# HTML Jquery move image left and right on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to HTML and jquery and I am trying to move a image left and right when a mouse hovers over the image in HTML page.

I think this could be done using jquery animate function but I cannot make it work.

Can someone please show me an easy HTML code on how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: please show us what you've tried so far

Comment: <head>
  <style>
 img {
    position: relative;}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('#box img').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        right: '2px'
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '2px'
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id = "box">
<img src="pathtimage/1.jpg" hspace="30"  height="350" width="220" >
</div>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: You can edit your answer to insert your code into the question - and format it so its readable.  Better, easier to understand questions get better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example, there are hundreds of different ways to it.

The CSS way:

```
#css img {
    left: 0px;
    transition: left .5s;
}
#css:hover img {
    left: 50px;
}
```

The JavaScript/jQuery way:

```
$('#js').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).find('img').css('left', '50px');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).find('img').css('left', '0px');
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nP7Lc/277/)

---

### Using animations:

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('#js').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        left: '50px'
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 500);
});
```

CSS transitions:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    margin:20px;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 500ms;
    -moz-transition: left 500ms;
    -ms-transition: left 500ms;
    -o-transition: left 500ms;
    transition: left 500ms;
}
#css:hover img {
    left:50px;
}
```

### [**Demo with both animation variants**](http://jsfiddle.net/nP7Lc/276/)

Comment: This is the code I wrote. What I want to do is image to move right when mouse hovers over it and come back to the same position when mouse is taken off the image. But what this is doing is the image goes to the left and disappears when mouse hovers over it. Please tell me what my mistake is

Comment: Code is<head> <style> img { position: relative;} </style> <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"; type = "text/javascript"></script> <script type = "text/javascript"> $('#box img').hover(function () { $(this).animate({ right: '2px' }); }, function () { $(this).animate({ left: '2px' }); }); </script> </head> <body> <div id = "box"> <img src="pathtimage/1.jpg" hspace="30" height="350" width="220" > </div> </body> </html>

Comment: @user2942227, the left parameter tells the distance to the left, so just make that value bigger and it will move to the right. No need to use `right: '2px'`. Did you see my demo? I Think just CSS is what you need here